# How can I curry an Expression into another Expression?

Tags: .net, expression, currying

I'm not sure if this is *strictly* currying, but I'm basically wanting to achieve the following. Given an `Expression`:

```
Expression<Func<T1, T2, TResult>> expression
```

I want to pass in *one* of the arguments and produce a corresponding `Expression` where the value for this parameter is fixed. The resulting expression should be functionally equivalent to `expression` except that it should contain one less parameter.

This resulting expression would look something like this:

```
Expression<Func<T2, TResult>> curriedExpression;
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work because an `Expression` doesn't implicitly convert to a lambda expression:

```
curriedExpression = b => expression(fixedValueForT1, b);
```

Note that `curriedExpression` shouldn't contain a call to `expression`; it should contain duplicated logic except with the fixed value.

I hope that makes sense. Let me know if this is ambiguous or not explained well.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just derive from the [`ExpressionVisitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) class in a simple way. Here's a proof of concept - it *may* be overly simplistic, but I think it's what you're after:

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<int, int, int>> original = (x, y) => MethodX(x) + MethodY(y);
        Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", original);
        var partiallyApplied = ApplyPartial(original, 10);
        Console.WriteLine("Partially applied: {0}", partiallyApplied);
    }

    static int MethodX(int x)
    {
        return x + 1;
    }

    static int MethodY(int x)
    {
        return -x;
    }

    static Expression<Func<T2, TResult>> ApplyPartial<T1, T2, TResult>
        (Expression<Func<T1, T2, TResult>> expression, T1 value)
    {
        var parameter = expression.Parameters[0];
        var constant = Expression.Constant(value, parameter.Type);
        var visitor = new ReplacementVisitor(parameter, constant);
        var newBody = visitor.Visit(expression.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T2, TResult>>(newBody, expression.Parameters[1]);
    }
}

class ReplacementVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression original, replacement;

    public ReplacementVisitor(Expression original, Expression replacement)
    {
        this.original = original;
        this.replacement = replacement;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == original ? replacement : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Original: (x, y) => (MethodX(x) + MethodY(y))
Partially applied: y => (MethodX(10) + MethodY(y))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any simpler way that's closer to the way you would do the same with `Func`s?

Comment: I fear there is no simpler way, when you work with expressions you must deal with syntactic structure, and this is always a fairly complicated business!

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that this is probably possible using [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), which you can obtain via NuGet [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/).

I don't have time at the moment to try it out for this example, but it's probably worth looking into so you don't have to use a solution like `ExpressionVisitor`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative to @jon-skeet implementation, with the following pros/cons:

Pros:

- The input expression can have 0..n arguments of any type.
- You can curry any of these parameters, by specifying the index of the replaced one.

Cons:

- You lose compile-time type safety (the input expression has no generic parameters, the index could be out of range and the replacement is an `object`).
- You must specify the type of the returned lambda expression.

```cs
private Expression<TLambda> Curry<TLambda>(
    LambdaExpression searchExpression, 
    int replacedParameterIndex, 
    object replacement)
{
    var parameter = searchExpression.Parameters[replacedParameterIndex];
    var constant = Expression.Constant(replacement, parameter.Type);
    var visitor = new ReplacementVisitor(parameter, constant);
    var newBody = visitor.Visit(searchExpression.Body);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<TLambda>(newBody, searchExpression.Parameters.Except(new[] { parameter }));

    return lambda;
}
```

So in the example of @jon-skeet we would use:

```
var partiallyApplied = Curry<int, int>(original, 0, 10);
```